# What controls the url used in the soap address location of the WSDL?

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I am exposing a wcf service over https from iis 6. I have verivied, as best I understand, that the binding is correctly set in iis (yes, positive that the site id is '1', and have done iisreset).

when I run this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>cscript.exe //NoLogo %sys
temdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs enum W3SVC/1
```

this is in the list:

```
SecureBindings                  : (LIST) (1 Items)
  ":443:dev.mydomain.com"
```

When I open the url to the service, I can see that it is correctly generating a url to the wsdl:

this:

```
https://dev.mydomain.com/virtual.directory/servicename.svc
```

specifies this url for svcutil.exe:

```
https://dev.mydomain.com/virtual.directory/servicename.svc?wsdl
```

However, when I inspect the wsdl itself, it stops using the domain, and replaces it with the machine name in this section of the wsdl xml:

```
<wsdl:service name="servicename">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_servicename" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_servicename">
<soap:address location="http://machinename.inernaldomain/virtual.directory/servicename.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Is my problem a web.config issue, or an IIS issue? Also, why does it change the soap address to http from https?

Comment: How configure IIS website for supports ***SSL (https)*** and what is the **system.model** configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake... I named my binding in the web config, but did not specify that binding to the service. All I had to do was clear the name of the binding . The simplified configuration for wcf services makes it so you dont have to specify a binding. In my case I just did not realize it was not seeing my binding (no error), and was using defaults. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx