# Add Service Reference take a https wsdl and generates a http endnpoint

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-binding, wcf-security

In VS2008 and 2010, when I add a service reference to a service that indicates https, the endpoint it creates is http. If I try to change the endpoint in the `app.config` to https, I get:

> The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
>   Parameter name: via

Comment: Exactly what do you mean that the service "indicates" https? Are you saying that only `https` is in the WSDL and not `http`?

Comment: when I add a service reference, I am giving it an https url for the wsdl. I have a cert setup, and I *believe the service is setup correctly for https. My question is why does Visual Studio create an http end point when I give it an https url to a service

Comment: Roger, you'll want to look at the WSDL to answer that question. I bet it's generating code based on the WSDL, not based on what URL you specify in "Add Service Reference".

Comment: John, you are correct, nothing will matter till the wsdl is fixed > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647015/what-controls-the-url-used-in-the-soap-address-location-of-the-wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `binding` the security is defined to be `<security mode="Transport">` ?

Transport means SSL, which have to be https://

Comment: Yes, the binding has mode set to Transport

Comment: bah.. it was the binding. I have the binding a name, but did not tell the service to use it. That mistake does not generate a configuration error, you just don't realize that wcf is ignoring your entry. All I had to do was clear the binding name, and it picked it up: <binding name="">. Thank you.